# Get image Height and Width

Tags: c#, wpf, image, resize

I am displaying an image which if small, will fill the size of the control area. I want to display the actual *original* width and height of the image.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 7):

[ImageSource.Width](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagesource.width.aspx) and [ImageSource.Height](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imagesource.height.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You actually kind of answered your own question.  There are two dependency properties that you can use: ActualWidth and ActualHeight.

This will give you the size that the picture is using on the screen, not what is currently set, which is what Width and Height give you.

Also, these dependency properties are useable by any FrameworkElement I believe.

[FrameworkElement.ActualWidth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualwidth.aspx)

[FrameworkElement.ActualHeight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.actualheight.aspx)

Comment: I think Jake is referring to the width and height of the image itself, not of the `Image` control...

Comment: @Thomas Oh you're probably right.  I'll leave my answer in case someone finds this looking for information on the control

Answer (score 0):

You can set the **Stretch** property to "None" to have an Image element use the actual source image size:

```
<Image Source="/Resources/MyImage.png" Stretch="None"/>
```