# How I get the X and the Y point of a image from a MouseEvent?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, events, mouse

I have a image editing program and need the X and the Y coordinate of the image. At the moment I use the MouseLeftButtonDown and MouseRightButtonDown event.

```
<Image Name="Image" MouseLeftButtonDown="MouseLeftButtonDown_Click" MouseRightButtonDown="MouseRightButtonDown_Click"></Image>
```

The problem I have is that I don't geht the right position on the picture in my WPF form. Means, if I drag the window smaller the coordinate is changing.

My method looks like this:

```
private void MouseLeftButtonDown_Click(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Point p = e.GetPosition(null);
    MessageBox.Show(p.X.ToString());
}
```

I think that the problem is that I add `null` as a argument in `e.GetPosition`. But I don't know what I have to add here otherwise...

> For example I open a 1920x1080 image I really want 1920 and 1080 if I
>   press the mouse at the right bottem corner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds as if you want the position with respect to the pixels of the original image, no matter what size the containing window is.

This should help...

```
private void MouseLeftButtonDown_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Point p = e.GetPosition(image);
    double pixelWidth = image.Source.Width;
    double pixelHeight = image.Source.Height;
    double x = pixelWidth * p.X / image.ActualWidth;
    double y = pixelHeight * p.Y / image.ActualHeight;
    MessageBox.Show(x + ", " + y);
}
```

I renamed your image to "image" to resolve the conflict between image name and class name. Update your XAML as follows:

```
<Image Name="image" MouseLeftButtonDown="MouseLeftButtonDown_Click" MouseRightButtonDown="MouseRightButtonDown_Click"></Image>
```

pixelWidth and pixelHeight are the original width and height of the source image.  x and y are calculated according the ratio between the original pixel width/height and the actual displayed width/height of the image on screen.

To display whole pixels in the popup message, use this instead:

```
MessageBox.Show((int)x + ", " + (int)y);
```

---

@Gerret: please can you give a few examples of the wrong coordinates, and what you were expecting them to be?

Comment: Well it is getting better. Now I get the same coordiant also if a drag the window smaller! But it seems like that the calculation is wrong. Because the position is wrong... It is nearly correct, maybe a offset from anywhere?

Comment: For example if I open a **1920x1080** picture and I click at the **right bottem corner** I get about **2500x1400**. If I open a **3500x2747** and I click at the **right bottem corner** I get about **2774x1938**. Please comment with a @ gerret in the comment section so i get a notification because I dont realized that you already ask me something if you add it in your answer!

Comment: Okay, never mind I found out that the resolution is wrong from the beginning so it is a other question. I will ask again here. Thank you for your help it helped me alot.

Comment: @Gerret, I'm glad to have helped you. Sorry for not being able to add a comment before; my StackOverflow reputation was not high enough! It is now :)

Answer (score 1):

instead of `null` try passing your `Image`

Like `System.Windows.Point p = e.GetPosition(Image);`

For Example:

Your Image:

```
<Image x:Name="imgYouImage" />
```

In your code use:

```
Point p = e.GetPosition(imgYouImage);
```

Comment: I don't know how I do that I have to add a System.Windows.IInputElement argument.

Comment: You need to pass you Image name instead of null.

Comment: So you mean the *class Image* or you mean my picture with the name *image*. If I use the *class Image* it is better but still not right. If I press at the left top corner I get the right coordinate but if I press at the right bottem corner I get a too small coordinate...

Comment: This is not working! I also can't cast it. How I have to add this argument... could you explain it further?

Comment: <Image x:Name="imgYouImage" /> then in your code use Point p = e.GetPosition(imgYouImage);

Comment: So I have solved that problem I don't realized that my WPF image is called the same as the class. So I still get the same problem as I described at my 3th comment. **If I press at the left top corner I get the right coordinate but if I press at the right bottem corner I get a too small coordinate...**

Comment: What you mean by too small coordinate, that i don't understand ? & I tried the same code on a 40x40 size Image and its showing me the correct coordinates weather i clicked at top left corner or at bottom right.

Comment: Like if I open a picture of 1920x1080 I only get 500x281 to 1775x996 (depends on how big I drag the window). I need the original coordinates so I can edit this point in my Bitmap!

Comment: when you drag the window, the e.GetPosition(imgYourImage); will give you the co-ordinates of the re sized window. This method will get you the current position of your cursor on a control with respect to the window size.

Comment: @gerret For the actual size and width refer an old post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1261237/get-image-height-and-width

Comment: @Vyas_27 So you know how I am able to calculate the real coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
System.Windows.Point p = e.GetPosition(Image);
```

As recommended by Simon Martin, I'll explain this...

GetPosition() returns the position of the mouse click in relation to the position of the element passed in as an argument.  If you pass in null, this will be relative to the position of the window, so you need to pass in your image name to get the correct coordinates.

Please see my other answer for a better solution.

Comment: Can you explain why your answer works, to make it more useful